# Testing Web Code

Tags: html, testing, web

Since html, CSS, and javascript show up slightly differently depending on the browser you use and the size of the screen, is there any way to quickly check what it would look like on each browser on different screen sizes. Kind of like something that emulates different screen sizes so I can quickly check without having many different sized computer screens.

Comment: Use http://browsershots.org/

Comment: Chrome has a pretty nice device emulator in it's developer tools that will allow you to explore your page in native device resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the link given to you in your question, to emulate size, there is a feature on google chrome where you go to your webpage, do Ctrl+shift+J and select the "Toggle device mode" feature.  That will resize your page based on a given size or selected device (such as an ipad).